# How to check installed extensions on database magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, database, module, table

I need to check installed module on database table

I hope your help

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: can you be more specific, please? what exactly are you looking for and why specifically in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check using following query.

SELECT * FROM setup_module WHERE module='Learning_GreetingMessage';

+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+
| module                   | schema_version | data_version |
+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Learning_GreetingMessage | 0.0.1          | 0.0.1        |
+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

- You can check the included modules with the help of the command:
  **php bin/magento module:status**
- Or you can look in the database table: **setup_module**

Answer (score 0):

command: **php bin/magento module:status Module_Name**
look in the database table: **setup_module**

Answer (score 0):

- Open Db
- Open table
- Find out your module name